# Huge amount of data persist using zustand

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, zustand

I want to persist my app data using zustand but in react native, but unable to use asyncstorage due to storage limitation 5 MB what other option do I have.

I tried to store huge amount of data using Zustand in AsyncStorage, Due to storage limitation unable to do it

Comment: What data you are trying to store in AsyncStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of AsyncStorage, you can use the React Native File System (react-native-fs) to store data in files on the device. This can be useful for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use something like react-native-sqlite-storage if you need to store large amounts of data. hope this helps.